# The variable is not updated when the storage is changed

Tags: javascript, angular, microservices, mobx

I have an angular application with a micro service architecture. I am using a mobx library to store the variable and update it in store everytime switchIsOpen method called

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(protected readonly store: Store) {
  }
  async ngOnInit() {}

  isOpen: boolean = true;

  switchIsOpen() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    sharedStateStore.setSharedVariable(this.isOpen);
  }
  
}
```

This is the store, the changes of the variable are seen in the console.log()

```
import { makeObservable, observable, action } from "mobx";

class SharedStateStore {
  @observable sharedVariable = true;

  @action setSharedVariable(value:boolean) {
    this.sharedVariable = value;
    console.log(this.sharedVariable)
  }

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this);
  }
}

export default new SharedStateStore();
```

This is a component that listens for changes to a variable in the store, but when I click the button that calls switchIsOpen() method in the first microfrontend changes just does not appear in the second component, but it gets the initial value of the isOpen variable from the store, which means he has access to the store, but not to the store changes.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tasklist',
  templateUrl: './tasklist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tasklist.component.scss'],
  providers: [MessageService,ConfirmationService]
})
export class TasklistComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  isOpen: boolean = sharedStateStore.sharedVariable;
  private disposeReaction: IReactionDisposer | null = null;

  constructor(
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.disposeReaction = reaction(() => sharedStateStore.sharedVariable, (isOpen) => {
      console.log('sharedVariable changed:', isOpen);
      this.isOpen = isOpen;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.disposeReaction) {
      this.disposeReaction();
    }
  }


}
```

This solution was suggested to me by ChatGPT, but id doesn't work, so maybe you can help me. Also the same issue was when I used NgRx

I have already written everything in the first field

Comment: what does `makeObservable(this)` do on the constructor of your store?

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli
In this specific case, makeObservable(this) is called in the constructor of the SharedStateStore class to enable MobX to observe changes to the sharedVariable observable and the setSharedVariable action. The observable decorator is used to mark sharedVariable as observable, and the action decorator is used to mark setSharedVariable as an action. These decorators are part of the ES7 (ECMAScript 2016) specification and allow MobX to observe and track changes to the sharedVariable property and the setSharedVariable method.

Comment: from what I understand from the documentation, you would need to pass to the class listening a decorator `@observer`, but the documentation I found is for react so idk. Can you try that?

Comment: which library can I get it from? both the mobx and the mobx-angular give the error "has no exported member 'observer'." when I try to import it

Comment: Have you tried makeObservable(this, { sharedVariable: observable }) alternatively use makeAutoObservable